# Confusion in Turings proof of the undecidability of the Entscheidungsproblem

Tags: turing-machines, turing-completeness

I was reading [Turing's paper on computable numbers and the Entscheidungsproblem](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Erobins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf). There is this part of Section 9, Part II that I cannot quite seem to understand. He says:

[image: Excerpt from Turing's "On Computable Numbers with an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem" where he defines a formula U that defines the sequence alpha generated by the function G(x), where x is a non-negative integer]

It is pretty straight forward until the part where he introduces $\mathfrak{U}$. So $\mathfrak{U}$, he says, includes the Peano axioms; but what else does it include? I guess it includes the axioms for $G(x)$ as well, because only then would $\mathfrak{U}$ be able to "define" the sequence $\alpha$ that is being computed by $G(x)$. I am taking the word "define" here in its usual sense, but Turing explains what he means by "$\mathfrak{U}$ defining $\alpha$" as:

[image: Excerpt from Turing's "On Computable Numbers with an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem" where he explained what he means by the formula U defining the sequence alpha]

So for $\mathfrak{U}$ to define $\alpha$, $-\mathfrak{U}$ must *not* be provable? I am not sure why that is required? Because by restricting that $-\mathfrak{U}$ must not be provable we are saying that $\mathfrak{U}$ must *not* be refutable, which means that the sequence $\alpha$ *cannot* be all 0's (or so I think). But why would we want $\alpha$ to not be all 0's?

I am also confused about the two formulas ($A_n$ and $B_n$) he has written above. I am not sure why if has included the $F^{(n)}$ part. If $x$ satisfies the Peano axioms and the axioms of $G(x)$, then $U$ being a conjection of all these axioms is given to be **TRUE**, and if $x$ does not satisfy these axioms then $\mathfrak{U}$ is obviously **FALSE**. So, just based on $\mathfrak{U}$ we can tell whether $A_n$ is **TRUE** or $B_n$. So what is the point of $F^{(n)}$ here? I think the following set of implications say pretty much the same thing as what Turing has?

[image: Another, possibly incorrect, formulation of the above implications]

Sorry if I am overlooking something here.

**Edit 1:**

Here are the footnotes:

[image: The footnotes refereed to in the excerpts attached above]

Comment: Regarding notation, we can use MathJax on this site. I've submitted an edit that makes use of it.

Comment: @user34258 Perfect! Thank you for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transliteration of the passage into modern langauge would go as follows.

We extend the language of first-order Peano arithmetic with a unary predicate $G$ (and no axioms for $G$).
For a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\overline{n}$ be the numeral
$$\underbrace{S(S(\cdots S}_{n}(0)))$$
where $S$ is the successor symbol. For example, $\overline{3} = S(S(S(0))$.

Consider a formula $\mathfrak{U}(x)$ written in this language, whose only free variable is $x$ such that, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

1. Peano axioms prove $\mathfrak{U}(\overline{n}) \Rightarrow G(\overline{n})$, or
2. Peano axioms prove $\mathfrak{U}(\overline{n}) \Rightarrow \lnot G(\overline{n})$.
3. Peano axioms do *not* prove $\lnot \mathfrak{U}(\overline{n})$.

Define $\alpha : \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ by
$$\alpha(n) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if Peano axioms prove $\mathfrak{U}(\overline{n}) \Rightarrow G(\overline{n})$},\\
0 & \text{if Peano axioms prove $\mathfrak{U}(\overline{n}) \Rightarrow \lnot G(\overline{n})$.}
\end{cases}
$$
We say that **$\mathfrak{U}$ defines the sequence $\alpha$**.

Intuitively, we think of $G(x)$ as stating "the $x$-th digit of $\alpha$ is $1$", and of $\lnot G(x)$ as stating "the $x$-th digits of $\alpha$ is $0$".

The first and second condition on $\mathfrak{U}$ ensure that $\mathfrak{U}$ always assigns $\alpha(n)$ the value $0$ or the value $1$.

The third condition ensures that $\mathfrak{U}$ never assigns *both* $0$ and $1$ to $\alpha(n)$ (because it follows from the first two conditions that $\lnot \mathfrak{U}(\overline{n})$ is equiprovable with $G(\overline{n}) \land \lnot G(\overline{n})$).

**Example:** The formula $G(x)$ defines the sequence $1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots$.

**Example:** The formula $G(S(x))$ does not define a sequence because $G(S(0)))$ does not imply $G(0)$ and it does not imply $\lnot G(0)$. (Remember that $G$ is a primitive symbol and that we have no axioms about it.)

**Example:** The formula $G(0) \land \forall x \,.\, \lnot G(S(x))$ defines the sequence $1, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$

**Example:** The formula $x \neq 0 \land \Rightarrow G(x)$ does not define the sequence because Peano axioms prove $\lnot (0 \neq 0 \land G(0)$, thus the third condition is violated. If we tried to use this formula to define a sequence, it would assign $0$ and $1$ to $\alpha(0)$ (and it would assign $1$ to all other terms of $\alpha$).

**Example:** The formula $G(0) \land \lnot G(S(0)) \land \forall x . G(S(S(x)))$ defines the sequence $1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots$

**Example:** The formula
$$((\exists y . x = 2 \cdot y) \Rightarrow G(x)) \land
  ((\exists y . x = S(2 \cdot y)) \Rightarrow \lnot G(x))
$$
defines the sequence $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, and the examples. By "extend[ing] the language of first-order Peano arithmetic with a unary predicate $G$" do you mean we add $G$ as the 10th axiom to it? Also, I cannot quite understand the definition of $\alpha$. It is 1 "if Peano axioms prove $\mathfrak{U}(\overline{n}) \Rightarrow G(\overline{n})$", but since $\mathfrak{U}$ is already constructed from (the extended) Peano axioms, shouldn't it always be provable using the Peano axioms. 
Sorry I only have a very basic & informal introduction to Logic (and that from Charles Petzold's The Annotated Turing)

Comment: A formal system has some *symbols* and *relations*. Peano arithmetic has symbols $0$, $S$, $+$ and $\times$. We add to it another symbol $G$. So this is not about axioms, but about what symbols we may use.

Comment: $\mathfrak{U}$ is not "constructed from Peano axioms". It is constructed using the symbols of the language ($0$, $S$, $+$, $\times$=, $G$, $=$ and all of first-order logic). The Peano axioms may be used to *prove or disprove* $\mathfrak{U}$.

Comment: For instance, $\mathfrak{U}$ could be the formula $S(S(x)) + S(0)  = x + x \Rightarrow G(x + S(0))$. It is constructed from the symbols of Peano arithmetic, $G$ and logical operators. Simply constructing or "writing down" a formula has nothing to do with axioms. The axioms become important when we try to prove or disprove the formula.

Comment: Ah, I see! Perfectly makes sense now. Thank you very much!